# Removing values from a multivalue field in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a table called Users with a multivalue field named Area. I am creating a simple SQL statement that simply deletes an area designated to a single user. *In the below example: Removing area "G1" from the user with a badge number of "123".*

Here's my SQL Statement:

```
DELETE Users.Area.Value
FROM Users
WHERE (((Users.Area.Value)="G1") AND ((Users.badgeNumber)="123"));
```

This somehow manages to result in an *Enter Parameter Value* dialog box. After double checking, all the parameters should be entered correctly. In fact, changing DELETE to SELECT creates a successful SQL statement.

Looking at the Microsoft help page, I found [this example](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-HA010149297.aspx#BM9).

```
DELETE Issues.AssignedTo.Value
FROM Issues
WHERE (((Issues.AssignedTo.Value)=6));
```

This removes a value from the entire database. I'd like to remove the value from just a  single user.

So now I am bit lost. Any help you can provide would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still unsure why the Enter Parameter dialog popped up, but I decided to just redo my code using the following method. It cleared out the entire User's area preferences and then set them again.

To clear the MVF area it looked like this:

```
DELETE Users.Area.Value
FROM Users
WHERE Users.BadgeNumber = "123"
```

To add to a MVF, I used the following:

```
Dim varReport As Variant
For i = 0 To Me.boxArea.ListCount - 1
    If Me.boxArea.Selected(i) = True Then
         sqlString = "INSERT INTO Users ([area].[Value]) VALUES ('" & Me.boxArea.Column(boundColumnZeroBasedIndex, i) & "') WHERE badgeNumber = '" + txtBadgeNumber + "';"
         CurrentDb.Execute sqlString, dbFailOnError
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same problem. It's unbelievable but changing the order in the where clause works:

```
DELETE Users.Area.Value
FROM Users
WHERE (((Users.badgeNumber)="123") AND ((Users.Area.Value)="G1"));
```